# GenyMotion Unable to start Virtual Device

Tags: genymotion

I'm trying to run my Virtual machine Android 5.1.1 Google Nexus 4 but it gives this error:

```
Unable to start virtual device.
VirtualBox Cannot start the virtual device.
```

[image: screenshot of error]

I have virtualisation enabled. How can I fix this?

Comment: were you able to get this fixed? I'm having the same problem. Admin more not helping...

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be detected within Windows10, I managed to fix it by opening Genymotion from your desktop access by enabling the execution of administrator.

Verify that you have the latest version installed, I hope this helps you.

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this fixed it:

- Go to Control Panel / Programs / Turn Windows features on or off
- Disable/Uncheck "Hyper-V"
- Click "OK" and restart PC.